# Any way to find why PHP ftp_get fail?

Tags: php, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Is there anyway to find why ftp_get fail , if connection was susccesfull?

Will error reporting or display error work for this.

Can anyone give a few general reasons why this function fail?

What will happen if the file is empty?

Comment: Turn on error_reporting and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons is that you have not set the connection type: active or passive. Call ftp_pasv before executing any file transfer.